# Terminal window size doesn't update using ioctl

Tags: c, terminal, size, ioctl

I'm using vanilla Ubuntu in a VM.  The code in question:

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void){
   struct winsize w;

   ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &w);
   printf("lines %d\n", w.ws_row);
   printf("columns %d\n", w.ws_col);

   printf("\033[8;40;100t");

   ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &w);
   printf("lines %d\n", w.ws_row);
   printf("columns %d\n", w.ws_col);

   return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run this, the original terminal window size is printed out, and then the window is resized to 40x100, but the last printf lines don't reflect the new terminal window size.

What is going on here, and how can I get updated terminal window size information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem in your code is obvious, after `printf("\033[8;40;100t");` you haven't flushed `stdout`. Thus when you call second `ioctl()`, those escape sequence is still in `stdout`'s buffer.

However, even if you add a `fflush(stdout);` most probably there is no change in the result. Because there is a race condition of whether the window is first resized or the next `ioctl()` is first called. It is still the case even if you add a `tcdrain()`.

This can be verified if you install a signal handler for `SIGWINCH`.

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <string.h>

void winsz_handler(int sig) {
    const char *s = "winsize changed!\n";
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, s, strlen(s));
}

int main(void){
   signal(SIGWINCH, winsz_handler);

   struct winsize w;

   ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &w);
   printf("lines %d\n", w.ws_row);
   printf("columns %d\n", w.ws_col);

   printf("\033[8;40;100t");
   fflush(stdout);
   tcdrain(STDOUT_FILENO);

   // remove this comment, then it works on my machine
   // However, it's ad hoc because there is no garantee
   //usleep(100000);

   ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &w);
   printf("lines %d\n", w.ws_row);
   printf("columns %d\n", w.ws_col);
   sleep(1);

   return 0;
}
```

The "winsize changed" output is the last one. If the `usleep()` in the comment is removed, then it works on my machine. Of course it's not a good solution for race condition.

Comment: there are several functions that should not be used in a signal handler.  `printf()` is one of those functions that should not be used.